# не собирается проэкт через intellij IDEA (build project)

Tags: java

есть большой проэкт над которым работаю.

Код пишу в **intellij IDEA**, время от времени нужно собирать проэкт , у нас это принято делать через **Maven** , но для удобства хотелось бы собирать его и в IDEA, чтоб сразу проверить , то , что я написал .

Но, когда выбираю , **build  project**  IDEA  начинает его собирать, но когда доходит до папки **d3v-api (build -Parsing java...[d3v-api]** , просто намертво зависает и ничего не происходит.

выдает ошибку в **build output:**

```
java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
```

может кто сталкивался, я человек новый в программировании , опыта пока не много.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Используется ли lombok (смотрите в pom.xml)?

Comment: @RomanKonoval          да, используется , подскажите решение?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего причина в том, что не включена интеграция IntelliJ с `lombok`, соответственно не работает генерация кода и т.д.

Установите плагин как описано [тут](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij).

Comment: Кажется, эту проблему решили, и теперь уже какая-то другая. Ее нужно бы описать, потому как у меня есть вопросы. В комментариях их задавать и особенно давать ответы неуместно и неудобно. Менять оригинальный вопрос можно, но это похоже несвязанные проблемы, так что лучше задать новый вопрос.